# Laravel Create range of date with Carbon Interval

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get range of date for example:

```
$startDate = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
$endDate = Carbon::now();
$period = new DatePeriod($startDate, CarbonInterval::day(), $endDate);

foreach ($period as $row) {
        $date = $row->format('Y-m-d');
        echo $date. ', &nbsp;';

}
```

Those code will return me this date:

```
2016-04-24,  2016-04-25,  2016-04-26,  2016-04-27, ... until 2016-05-23
```

But the problem is, the date not return today's date (2016-05-24).

How can I get today date using above code?

Thanks.

---

I can get today date buy changing `$endDate = Carbon::now();` to `$endDate = Carbon::now()->tomorrow();`

But its a little bit odd when read the code.

Comment: Which dates do you get in `$startDate` and `$endDate` ?

Comment: $startDate = 2016-05-23. $endDate = 2016-05-24.

I've update with my current solution

Comment: Have you tried `$startDate = Carbon::now(); $startDate->subWeek()` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $numberOfDays = $endDate->diffInDays($startDate);
    foreach (range(0, $numberOfDays) as $day) {
        $dates[] = $endDate->copy()->subDays($day)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```